# Getting point cloud from image_rect_color using stereo_image_proc

Tags: ros, stereo-camera, stereo, stere-image-proc, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a bag publishing left and right camera_info and image_rect_color topics.
How can I use stereo_image_proc to get the point cloud?

stereo_image_proc/disparity nodelet subscribes to image_rect and gives out disparity, which can be used by the stereo_image_proc/point_cloud2 nodelet.

Do I need to modify the source code, make a custom launch file or this can be done via an easier way that I am unable to see immediately?
Afai understand, I have to convert to mono image and then maybe remap or publish to the relevant topic.

ROS_NAMESPACE=stereo rosrun stereo_image_proc stereo_image_proc -> here the whole node subscribes to raw images which I don't have as a topic.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218319/getting-point-cloud-from-image_rect_color-using-stereo_image_proc/) by [ratneshmadaan](https://answers.ros.org/users/12636/ratneshmadaan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2015-09-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ratneshmadaan](https://answers.ros.org/users/12636/ratneshmadaan/) on 2015-09-27**:
https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline/blob/indigo/stereo_image_proc/src/nodes/stereo_image_proc.cpp. Read the source. So, I need to comment out the debayer and rectify blocks. But I need an image_rect from image_rect_color(color to mono basically?) and then I can use the two nodelets.

**Comment by [ratneshmadaan](https://answers.ros.org/users/12636/ratneshmadaan/) on 2015-09-29**:
As I had zero distortion - plumb bob model, with the parameters needed being [0,0,0,0,0], all I needed to do was remap:
`rosbag play my_bag_file.bag /my_cam/left/image_rect_color:=/my_cam/left/image_raw /my_cam/right/image_rect_color:=/my_cam/right/image_raw`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As I had zero distortion - plumb bob model, with the parameters needed being {0,0,0,0,0}, all I needed to do was remap: `rosbag play my_bag_file.bag /my_cam/left/image_rect_color:=/my_cam/left/image_raw /my_cam/right/image_rect_color:=/my_cam/right/image_raw`

---

Originally posted by [ratneshmadaan](https://answers.ros.org/users/12636/ratneshmadaan/) with karma: 71 on 2015-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0